# How to create drawable in xml, with inverse rounding?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-drawable

I need to create in xml next drawable:
 [image]

How can I achieve this?
I only know how to make right-top rounding - but what about bottom-right inverse rounding?

Comment: Try create custom 9-patch image.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a nine patch image to do this.

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch.html

Example tool:
https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/nine-patches.html#&sourceDensity=320&name=example

A nine patch is a png image with black pixels in the borders to delimitate the area that has to be extended. The format is `example.9.png`, `.9.png` is the extension.

A little tutorial, you can find others:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLimJf-EIl8